# jquery get elements loaded from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a form from html file multiple times inside div. I want to loop through these elements which have been created inside this div.

I wrote the following code to load the files on each button click:

```
 function addForm()
{
    file = "field.php";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ctrl_fields").append( $('<div />').load(file));
    });
}
```

now, I want to loop through the files that have been loaded (file.php) which contains some html code.
I wrote the following but it doesn't work:

```
$("#ctrl_fields").each(function(){

   // do something here

});
```

Comment: Oh, `load` into an empty element inside an `append`. That sorta defeats the purpose and you should probably use `$.ajax` or `$.get` the regular way instead.

Comment: I am not lading an empty element. I am loading the file multiple times each time into the empty div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#ctrl_fields > div ").each(function(){
   $(this).doSomething(); //this is the current div
});
```

Comment: Thanks aldux. I get inside the main div now. but how to get the elements there. for example, I want to read the text in one of the inputs in that file: I wrote this but it does not work:  alert($(this).getElementById('txt_len').value)